# Object is possibly `undefined` even though it can't be

Tags: typescript

Reading through other answers it may be how Typescript statically analyses the code, if that is the case if someone is able to explain further that'd be great.

Here is my code, I can't see how it could be undefined, yes you may call `foo({})` or `foo({ algorithm: undefined })` but it'd be then merged with `default` and the resulting object would always have `algorithm`

```js
type Options = {
    algorithm?: string;
    identifier?: string;
}

const defaults: Options = {
    algorithm: 'sha256',
    identifier: 'Fizz',
}

function foo(options: Options = defaults) {
    options = { ...defaults, ...options };

    if (!(options.algorithm in someOtherObj)) { // Object is possibly 'undefined'.

    }

    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(someOtherObj, options.algorithm)) {
      /**
        Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropertyKey'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'PropertyKey'.
      **/
    }

    if (someOtherObj[options.algorithm]) { // Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.
                
    }
}

foo();
```

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgEMAbAcyQCcFgALAWwH4AuKNYGlcgbgKIQATCCkQAzBBCqt2nBNz4BfPHgDGqDlGFjiAV1LA0bOIg1Zc-QmUo16DNgHI0dYgCYArADYHAGktQhEXFJKkcAMQQAL0jfPGU8MV0UVVMUKDEkJAAKJHhkdGM8s2xtPQM0AEoLIihc1IxsHCgAOlbS-UMfFta6-IxFPn8EMSgsgEIcovRm62paRgC03o0Kqvx-eJrh0ZgAIwArCBTmlzQYAHcUAAUqXKlQZtUyUkn6ruXp2dtGVYsNlS2I1efQA2h80DMKHM7ABdNb+GqIoj-eIZbIVHhAA

Comment: Surely you just want `"algorithm"` though? `options.algorithm` is the string type, you would be looking for the property `sha256` by default.

Comment: Sorry it was a simplified version of my actual code that looked at a different object. I just did it like that for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the type of `options` is declared as `Options`. If you assign a new value to that type, it's still of type `Options`, and `Options` can have undefined properties.

Same goes for `defaults`. It's of type `Options`, so the fact that you've assigned strings for its properties doesn't matter. It's treated as type `Options` because you've told it to be that. type.

In short, by declaring type of a variable or constant, you override what typescript might infer about it.

---

I would model this differently.

Make the `Options` type require all properties.

```
type Options = {
    algorithm: string;
    identifier: string;
}
```

Now `defaults` can use that type, and it will even enforce you have a value for each property.

```
const defaults: Options = {
    algorithm: 'sha256',
    identifier: 'Fizz',
}
```

Now your function can say it only needs a `Partial<Options>` meaning that all properties are considered optional. Then merge your defaults into a new variable. Now typescript can see that no value could be undefined because one of the types you are merging it with cannot have undefined properties.

```
function foo(options: Partial<Options> = {}) {
    const optionsNotNull = { ...defaults, ...options };
    //...
}
```

Or more conveniently with destructuring:

```
function foo(options: Partial<Options> = {}) {
    const { algorithm, identifier } = { ...defaults, ...options };
    //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgEMAbAcyQCcFgALAWwC4o1gaVyBuAohAEwgpEAMwQQqLNh254AvnjwBjVGyiCRxAK6lgaFnESqsuXoTKUa9ZlADkaOsQBMAVgBstgDRmoAoaPFJOwAxBAAvMK95RREtFCUjFCgRJCQACiR4ZHQWAAViKkQyAB5DbLQAPhMcOQBKUyIoFXRgKEzEtAA5JGBOnVIDLONsHCgAOgmNbV00T3GJ9vKoOR4fBBEoNIBCDKH0bt7+sYtqWkZfJMXVWvr8HwU1jbSYACMAKwgEscc0GAB3FC5KiZCSgMZKMikXYdOZXfY9PqkUjHCinaw3Uz3aJ4FLpWo8XFpGr4nGpIkkVFWRgsOIaBAoCD8ZYkwmjE5Umy2Bj8Fy2ZlcIA)

---

Lastly, `if (options[options.algorithm])` isn't going to work because `Options` is not indexable by `string`. Or to put another way, `sha256` is not a property of `options`. So typescript won't let you do that. None of the above will change that.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The options parameter in `foo` is typed as Options, which is defined as having optional properties, regardless of what you do to the assignment of the variable.

Finally, the implementation of the `foo` function assumes that a function lives on the options object itself, which isn't typed anywhere. To make it type safe and double the options variable as the host for the actual functions, you could do something like the following:

```js
type Algorithms = 'sha256';

type Options = {
    algorithm?: Algorithms;
    identifier?: string;
}

type AlgorithmFns = {
    [key: string]: string | Function;
}

const defaults: Required<Options> & AlgorithmFns = {
    algorithm: 'sha256',
    identifier: 'Fizz',
    sha256: () => {}
}

function foo(options?: Options) {
    const opts: Required<Options> & AlgorithmFns = { ...defaults, ...options };

    if (!(opts.algorithm in opts)) {

    }

    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(opts, opts.algorithm)) {

    }

    if (typeof opts[opts.algorithm] === 'function') {
                
    }
}

foo();
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNgcwPYCcCWwAWBbAzlAXigHJdMBDAJgFYA2YgbgCgnRIoB5MYNJAO3xEA3kyhio5RKgw4A-AC5YU9FjzNxUNABMIfHgDM0EFAqi5g6PgmYBfFm2jxkKnADEBhKCI0BtANYQIIrmlggAusEWaFZQAD5QrgCufADGPPy2LCn85lA6%20uSJcMC4igBKEACOiWgoEFoAPFzpAgB8UABkSs4y2O6CXqLikj2qiqQUNPQANENi2roGRijjrmgAXuvEsxpkVHSKABQAlITtQnZ2TPrJabx8UPpISIdI3Pe4ps0fp97i2QJgFA3iVylUanVGt8cu0uk5pKp%20p4hFAAHTo-KFYq4aZo9Egj5QGzMOaafRQQ4AQle3FwqJGCJwmgeINwx1%20LA0Vw0aHJhw4ACMAFYQNKoii4DgAdz4AAUUG9jKBUSlJHAaSVcaz6cpeuzBqTueJeRSHEhyayfNqGS5sGFCAQiMQbqkWsQORpPV6oIamFcni9jgwgA)