# Typescript thinks object may be undefined even though it is defined

Tags: typescript

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277887/object-is-possibly-undefined-even-though-it-cant-be) with a similar name although the problem is different.

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of an attribute in a list of a objects.

```
let objArray = [{state: 'North Carolina'},{state: 'Florida'}]

let res = new Map<string, number>();
for (let obj of objArray) {
    if (res.get(obj.state)) {
      res.set(obj.state, res.get(obj.state)+1)
    } else {
      res.set(obj.state, 1)
    }
}
```

But typescript flags `res.get(obj.state) + 1` because `res.get(obj.state)` may be `undefined` (which I don't think is possible).

I'd also be equally fine with `let res = {}` but when I write analogous code for that typescript doesn't like trying to index `res` by `string`.

I'm kinda at a loss for what typescript expects me to do to accomplish my simple task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler should be happy if you extract the repeated use of `res.get(obj.state)` into a variable:

```
let objArray = [{state: 'North Carolina'},{state: 'Florida'}]

let res = new Map<string, number>();
for (let obj of objArray) {
    const state = res.get(obj.state);
    if (state) {
      res.set(obj.state, state+1)
    } else {
      res.set(obj.state, 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!` seems to work:

```
res.get(obj.state)! + 1
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgQQE5IIYE8IF4IG0DeAzmKmCAFwQDkAclEmABYQDCqSUwAlgHapUBfADRESZSlQBiwelwAm-AQF0AUCtCQkIQtgg8QAdwgBZVAAcAPMSS8A5kL0BXALYwQSAHwAKAJQBuFQAzeggvDWh4aECIxBQMHwh8FQgUiC5ory1CADpbcC9YOGziUhAfBKTU1Kzi-MLisRAHGrywAvgG0p8AQggAaggARh9k1IEIEGBCEETRqprptvqSsgdhuYgBFQEgA)

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide a brief explanation of what `!` does?

Comment: In general I would avoid asserting that something is not null, when there are is a way to let the compiler infer that.

Comment: I agree, I'm going to go with your answer, but I think it's still useful to know

Comment: There's a good explanation on this post (basically 'non-null assertion operator'): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/258113